# Input: a2b3c4 and Output: aabbbcccc

Tags: c, string

The code I've written is not producing any output. It just takes the string as an input:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    int i,size,s,pos;
    scanf("%s", &str);
    size=strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if((str[i]>=65 && str[i]<=90) || (str[i]>=97 && str[i]<=122)) {
            i++;
        } else {
            if(str[i]>='0' && str[i]<='9') {
                for(s=0;s<str[i];s++) {
                    printf("%s", str[i-1]);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dear God... please format the code!

Comment: If this isn't for *code golf*, try some newlines...

Comment: While copy-pasting, please make sure you at least paste the entire program.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &str); `?? or `scanf("%s", &str[0]); `??

Comment: Why are you using magic numbers like 65 etc? Please lookup `isalpha`

Comment: Your whole code depends on ASCII, not a good thing in general. This line: `for(s=0;s<str[i];s++)` loops up to the *code* of your number character, not what you want. you mean `for(s=0;s<str[i]-'0';s++)` here. Probably MANY other errors.

Comment: `printf("%s", str[i-1]);` : type of `str[i-1]` is `char`. But `%s` of `printf` requires `char *`

Comment: And what's `conio.h` about? This isn't standard C and is not needed here at all!

Comment: Please **don't add pictures of code**. If you don'lt like the code formatting, edit it to show your formatting, but keep it there **as text**.

Comment: I was trying to format the code but stack overflow was showing errors so i preferred to add a screenshot of the code. It would be great of you if you can help me with this code as i am new to programming

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/fTQUBp)

Comment: @UmangJain I found **at least** four instances of *undefined behavior* in this code, see my answer. Take the advice and enable compiler warnings. They can't possibly warn about **any** undefined behavior, but you would have caught some...

Comment: What's the expected output for a2b3c14? How about a2b3c0? BTW—This is a type of Run-length encoding (RLE).

Comment: @TomBlodget The characters will be printed the number of times specified after that particular character. Similarly, a2b3c0 will produce 2 times 'a' , 3 times 'b' and 0 times 'c'.

Comment: And how about for input "abc"? If these are valid inputs, you should use them as tests? It's never too early to learn a unit test framework. A key advantage is that it helps define the requirements when you write the test code before the implementation code.

Comment: @TomBlodget Sure, I will do it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char str[100];
int i=0,s;
scanf("%s",str);
while(str[i]!='\0')
{ 
    if(str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') 
    {
        i++;            
    }
    else if(str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z')
    { 
        i++; 
    }

    else if(str[i]>='0' && str[i]<='9')
        {

            for(s=0;s<str[i]-'0';s++)
            {
            printf("%c", str[i-1]);
            }
            i++;

        }

}
```

}

Comment: @Felix Palmen , The code works fine now. thankyou for the additional help.
:)

Comment: Try entering `"@"` --> infinite loop.

Comment: For this we can put checks so that wrong input is not entered. @chux

Answer (score 5):

This whole code has many errors:

- You try to print a single character with `%s`, which is for strings. This leads to **undefined behavior** -- the correct conversion for a single character is `%c`.
- You loop until some "digit character" like `'3'`. You want to loop until the number `3` instead. Subtract `'0'` to achieve this.
- Doing `scanf("%s", ...)` is potential **undefined behavior**, it will eventually overflow any buffer. You might want to read my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). In short, **at least** add a field width, in your case `scanf("%99s", ...)`
- `scanf()` expects a pointer to where to put the data, but `str` already evaluates to a pointer to the first array element. Therefore adding `&` is **wrong** here, leading to more **undefined behavior**.
- Always **check the return value** of functions that might fail. If your `scanf()` fails to convert something, your `str` stays uninitialized and the following `strlen()` is **undefined behavior**.
- Your code uses ASCII values, which is *very* common, but not mandated; this way, it won't work on machines not using ASCII.

It's not even necessary to use a buffer for what you want to achieve, a single character to save the last character read is sufficient, like this (the other issues are fixed in this example as well):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int l = EOF;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (isdigit(c) && isalpha(l))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < c-'0'; ++i)
            {
                putchar(l);
            }
        }
        l = c;
    }

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

---

As some further advice:

- Compile with compiler warnings enabled, e.g. when using `gcc`, add these flags:

  ```
  -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
  ```

  this would have identified some of the problems in your code already.
- Read a good book on C **and** look up individual functions in *manual pages* (on a *nix system, try typing `man 2 printf` for example .. you can also just feed it to google and find web versions of these pages)

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
   char str[50];
    int i=0,j,k,c;
    printf("Enter  String :  ");
    scanf("%s",&str);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);) {
        for(j=0;j<str[i+1]-'0';j++) {
            printf("%c",str[i]);
        }
    i=i+2;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works perfect! But one thing, the [^\ is not a good practice and generates a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code.May be help you.It's similar to your code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char str[100],ch;
int i,len,s,pos,k;
scanf("%s", &str);
len=strlen(str);
int number=0;
for(i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    if((str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') || (str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z'))
    {
        for(k=0;k<number;k++)
        {
            printf("%c",ch);
        }
        ch=str[i];
        number=0;
    }
    else
    {
        number=number*10+(str[i]-'0');
    }
}
for(k=0;k<number;k++)
{
    printf("%c",ch);
}
printf("\n");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 50
void main()
{
    char name[MAX],str1[MAX],str3[MAX];
    int str2[MAX],i,j,m,t=0;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Your name is %s.", name);
    for(j=0,i=0;name[i]!='\0';i=i+2,j++)
    {
        str1[j]=name[i];
        str2[j]=name[i+1]-'0';
    }
    for(i=0;i<=strlen(str1);i++)
    {
        for(j=str2[i];j>0;j--)
        {
            str3[t]=str1[i];
            printf("%c",str3[t]);
            t++;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char str[200] , ch;
int ind , count;
scanf("%s" , str);
int len , start;
for(len=0 ; str[len] ; len++);
start=len ;
ind=count=0;
while( ind < len )
{
    ch = str[ind++];
    while(str[ind] >= '0' && str[ind] <= '9' )
        count = count * 10 + (str[ind++] - '0');
    while(count)
    {
        str[start++] = ch;
        count--;
    }
}
for(ind=len ;ind < start ;ind++)
    str[ind - len]=str[ind];
str[ind - len] = 0;
printf("%s" , str);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanations to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the brute force approach in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string s = "a3b3c4";
   int n = s.length();
   string w = "";
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
      if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
          for(int j=0;j<s[i]-'0';j++) {
              w += s[i-1];
          }
      }
   }
  cout<<w<<endl;
}
```

The output will be:

```
aaabbbcccc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def decompress_str(com):
    ls = []
    for i in range(0,len(com),2):
        times = int(com[i+1])
        while times:
            ls.append(com[i])
            times -= 1
    print("".join(ls))

input = "a2b3c4"
decompress_str(input) # output aabbbcccc
```

Here:

1. I'm taking every even index(0,2,4) as the alphabet, and printing it for odd index(1,3,5) times. Appending the output to a list.
2. Later, I'm changing the list to a string using join().

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s ="A9B3C4D5";
    for(int i =0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i)>='A' && s.charAt(i)<='Z'){
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        }else{
            int a = s.charAt(i)-48;
            
            for(int j =1; j <a; j++) {
                System.out.print(s.charAt(i-1));
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

output :-AAAAAAAAABBBCCCCDDDDD

Comment: it is easy way to solve the above question try is

Comment: Provide supplementary comments to your answer in the answer itself and use the comment option for questions about your answer, it makes reviewing easier.

Answer (score -2):

Check out this code:-

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int j = 0, sum = 0, k = 0;
    char str[100];
    cout << "Enter string:- ";
    cin >> str;
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            sum = sum + (str[i] - '0');
            for (j = 1; j <= sum; j++) {
                cout << str[k];
            }
            k=k + 2;
        }
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what edits you made and why it solves OP's problem? What about this code should I check out?

Comment: Heyy, First of all I haven't made any edits in the original code. The main thing which was missing in the original one was the loop which multiplied the characters with the numbers written after them. Secondly, the code itself is much easier to understand that's why I that you can check this code out. The code uses a simple approach which is to get the number and then runs the loops to repeat the alphabet written before the number. I hope it helps. 

Comment: Please [edit] to update instead of commenting.