# Reading input from a file, changing it, and printing to a new file

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to write a program that would read input from one file, edit it, and prints to another file. The edits would be: if it reads 4A3B, it would print AAAABBB. If it reads 2C1D, it would print CCD. The new file would not have any numbers in it. So far all I've been able to figure out is how to just copy the first file into the second one.

I'm not sure how to go about the changes I need. Is there a way to write a function that can differentiate between numbers and letters when reading from a file?

My code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
FILE *first, *second;
char letter;
int num;

first= fopen("first.txt", "r");
second= fopen("second.txt", "w");

if (first== NULL) { 
    printf("File doesn't exist.\n");
}


while ((a = fgetc(first)) != EOF) {
    fprintf(second, "%c", a);
}

//fprintf(second, "


fclose(first);
fclose(second);
return(0);
```

}

Comment: Will the numbers in the first file only be single digits? Then read two characters at a time, convert the first to a number, and write to the second character to the second file in a loop (use e.g. `fputc` instead of `fprintf`).

Comment: By the way, assuming that `letter` and `a` are supposed to be the same variable, remember that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**. Which is rather important when you want to compare its value to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: If the numbers can be multiple digits (e.g. 10B22A), I'd use `fscanf("%d%c", &num, &letter);` to read each number/character pair. Be sure to check the value that `fscanf` returns. Since two conversions are requested, the return value should be 2. If it's not, the file either has a typo in it, or you've reached the end of the file. Either way, the loop that's reading the file should end.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Reading compressed Ascii art from a file, decompressing, and printing to another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69353431) and [Input: a2b3c4 and Output: aabbbcccc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436599)

Comment: `"File doesn't exist.\n"` is an incorrect and misleading error message.  Try `perror("first.txt");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input: a2b3c4 and Output: aabbbcccc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436599/input-a2b3c4-and-output-aabbbcccc)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure how to go about the changes I need.

- Read in pairs of characters into `int`s.
  `fgetc()` typically returns 257 different values: [0-255] and `EOF` (some negative).  Save in an `int`.

> ... differentiate (characters) between numbers and letters ...

- Test using `is....()`

Sample code

```
#include <ctype.h>
...

  int n, a;
  while (isdigit(n = fgetc(first)) && isalpha(a = fgetc(first))) {
    printf("Pair %c:%c\n", n, a);
    // Change digit character into value
    int repeat_count = n - '0';

    for (int i = 0; i < repeat_count; i++) {
      fprintf(second, "%c", a);
    }
  }
```

---

Alternatively, use `fscanf()` as the above does not read `"123A"` as 123 `'A'`.

`"%d"` to read text as a number.
`"%1[A-Za-z]"` to read a sequence of letters (up to 1) into a *string*.

```
  int n;
  char a[2];
  while (fscanf(first, "%d%1[A-Za-z]", &n, a) == 2) {
    printf("Pair %d:%c\n", n, a[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      fprintf(second, "%c", a[0]);
    }
  }
```